# Where do questions about general aspects of numerical optimisation go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Are there any more appropriate sites in the Stack Exchange network for posting questions about general aspects of numerical optimisation, like goal function specification, dealing with local minimum etc.?

Comment: 'more appriopriate' than what?  Why ask about that subject here?   Which sites did you consider?  'donutfillings.com' is more appropriate than SO, so a literal answer would be 'yes'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a sister site 
[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) which [welcomes](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - Questions about **algorithms or methods used to solve problems in applied mathematics** (e.g., finding roots of a polynomial, finding the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a matrix, solving an elliptic/parabolic/hyperbolic PDE)
> - Questions that ask about appropriate **methods for a given application area** (e.g., what numerical methods would I use when modeling shock waves, what numerical methods would I use when modeling combustion, what graph algorithms would I use if I wanted to understand social networks)

This *looks* similar to what you're asking, but we can only know for sure if you have a concrete question you want to ask.