# What StackExchange site is best suited for questions on algorithms?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question concerning a specific algorithem (but not a specific coding language), where is the most suitable StackExchange site to ask this? (Or what non-StackExchange site would be better suited, if there is really no good one within StackExchange?)

Essentially, I'm thinking of (more detailed) questions of the following kind:

*I want to compute local intensity maxima in a 2D array of values, what are the most efficient alogorithms to do this?*

or also the other way around

*I have the following algorithm to compute local intensity maxima in a 2D array (..`pseudoCode`..). How could it be improved or do you see problems with it?*

Note, while these are questions on the algorithm, the aim of them is to get *practical* answers tied to actually coding them up (or learning of libraries that can be used.) While a part of them might be in the realms of pure mathematics, they are not direclty questions aimed on mathematicians for the "perfect" answer.

Comment: The question itself is different, but I could post [my answer there](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362124/4751173) *verbatim* (except for the last sentence, I guess).

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks. Your linked answer *did* answer my question. However, I did not come across it when searching.

Comment: Neither did it for me but I remembered having answered this kind of question before :)

Comment: In any case, yet another exciting SE community I'll have to join! :c}

Comment: The scicomp seems to be more of scientific computation related. Isn't there any site that is for problems like complexity analysis, graph algorithms, tree stacks and queues?